# Robust way to sum all values corresponding to a particular objects property?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have an array as such.

```
items = [
  {
    "title": "title1",
    "category": "category1",
    "value": 200
  },
  {
    "title": "title2",
    "category": "category2",
    "value": 450
  },
  {
    "title": "title3",
    "category": "category1",
    "value": 100
  }
]
```

This array consists of many dictionaries with a property `category` and `value`.
What is the robust way of getting an array of category objects with their `value` summed like:

```
data= [
  {
    "category": "category1",
    "value": 300
  },
  {
    "category": "category2",
    "value": 450
  }
]
```

I'm looking for the best algorithm or way possible for both the small array as well as the huge array. If there is an existing algorithm please point me to the source.

What I tried??

```
data = []
for each item in items:
    if data has a dictionary with dictionary.category == item.category:
        data's dictionary.value = data's dictionary.value + item.value
    else:
        data.push({"category": item.category, "value":item.value})
```

Note: Any programming language is welcome. Please comment before downvoting.

Comment: Well my comment would be to ask what you have tried already? You could do this in a single pass of the list.

Comment: Hint: Maintain a hash of those keys.

Comment: I am sure there is already an answer to this question. For efficiency you need to start with setting up a look up table or Map object as the value of `category` property being the key. I would use this Map object as an initial value of `.reduce()`. Somebody will definitly give the answer if this has no duplicate.

Comment: @Redu I just couldn't find the right words to search this. And could you please explain briefly in an answer? I need to consider all probable solutions.

Comment: [Eddie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52679895/4543207) is pretty close to what i am saying. He is using an object literal as a look up table (initial value of `.reduce()`) while i would use a Map object. Map objects are faster i suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript, you can use `reduce` to group the array into an object. Use the category as the property. Use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array.

```js
var items = [{
    "title": "title1",
    "category": "category1",
    "value": 200
  },
  {
    "title": "title2",
    "category": "category2",
    "value": 450
  },
  {
    "title": "title3",
    "category": "category1",
    "value": 100
  }
];

var data = Object.values(items.reduce((c, v) => {
  c[v.category] = c[v.category] || {category: v.category,value: 0};
  c[v.category].value += v.value;
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a SQL `group by` like operation. Usually, those `group by` operations are handling with hashing algorithms. If all your data could fit in memory (small to large data structures) you can implement it very quickly.

If your data structure is huge, you will need to use intermediate memory (such as hard drive or database).

An easy python approach will be:

```
data_tmp = {}
for item in items:
    if item['category'] not in data_tmp:
        data_tmp[item['category']] = 0
    data_tmp[item['category']] += item['value']
data = []
for k, v in data_tmp.items():
    data.append({
        'category': k,
        'value': v
    })
# done
```

If you want more pythonic code you can use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data_tmp = defaultdict(int)
for item in items:
    data_tmp[item['category']] += item['value']
data = []
for k, v in data_tmp.items():
    data.append({
        'category': k,
        'value': v
    })
# done
```

Comment: That's why I said a `group by` **like** operator. Not an actual SQL `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, Pandas is likely to be a more convenient and efficient way of doing this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(items)
sums = df.groupby("category", as_index=False).sum()
data = sums.to_dict("records")
```

For the final step, it may be more convenient to leave `sums` as a dataframe and work with it like that instead of converting back to a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Actually, I was looking for an algorithm. Shouldn't use any internal/external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Using *itertools.groupby*

```
d = []

lista = sorted(items, key=lambda x: x['category'])
for k, g in groupby(lista, key=lambda x: x['category']):
    temp = {}
    temp['category'] = k
    temp['value'] = sum([i['value'] for i in list(g)])
    d.append(temp)

print(d)
# [{'category': 'category1', 'value': 300}, {'category': 'category2', 'value': 450}]
```